# jarsigner error: X.509 not found

Tags: java, ant, jarsigner

I am using Ant to build a Java project. One of the last steps in the build.xml file is to sign the jar, using the following `signjar` task (generic values used, also uses nested paths):

```
<signjar keystore="C:/path/to/keystore" 
  storepass="storepass" 
  alias="alias" 
  keypass="keypass" 
  lazy="true">
```

All of the fields are correct (I have verified by writing a small Java program that shows the keystore entry with the correct passwords and aliases). When building with Ant, however, the build fails at the `signjar` task with the exception:

```
[signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: certificate exception: X.509 not found
```

I cannot find anything on SO or elsewhere documenting this exception; can someone explain what this means and how I can fix it?

EDIT: I ran again with the `-v` argument, and now have a stacktrace if that helps:

```
jarsigner returned: 1
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:644)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SignJar.signOneJar(SignJar.java:534)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SignJar.execute(SignJar.java:449)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
```

Comment: Write a simple java program and check if the certificate is there in the keystore.

Comment: Looks like either JCE (Java Cryptography Extensions) is not installed properly or is not on the Classpath for your ANT build.

Are you using the same JDK for your ANT build as for your test program accessing the keystore?